# How can I allocate memory for a char** and all of its char*'s in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

I'm trying to allocate memory like this:

[image: unknown_memory_2001]

I thought that I'd use malloc for the `char**`:

```
char** arr = malloc(sizeof(char**)*(SIZE));
```

And then I thought I'd loop through `arr` and set each value of `arr` to what's returned by another `malloc` call:

```
char** temp = arr;
while(temp < arr + SIZE) {
    *temp = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(SIZE));
    temp++;
}
```

But I segfault on the `malloc` line within the while loop. What's going wrong?

Comment: Not immediately sure on the segfault, but you should have sizeof(char*) and sizeof(char) if you think about it.

Comment: Both of your `sizeof` arguments are wrong.  Think about what you're actually allocating.  The first should be `sizeof(char *) * SIZE` and the second `sizeof(char) * SIZE`.  Remember, the argument to `sizeof` in `malloc` should always have one less level of indirection than the resulting pointer type.

Comment: That doesn't explain your bug by the way - it's just wasteful especially in the second instance where you're probably allocating 4 times as much memory as you need.  What is the value of `SIZE`?  If it's large enough, you could be running out of memory (and you're not checking the return value from `malloc`, which you really should).

Comment: Is SIZE so large that the first malloc is failing?   You should ALWAYS check the return of malloc for failure.

Comment: It's quite odd that `SIZE` is being used for both the number of strings and the length of each string.

Comment: I just tried this code with varying values for `SIZE`, and found no issue. Is this the **exact** code you ran yourself (i.e., copy-and-paste)?

Comment: @TomKarzes it's not likley malloc will fail, `sizeof(char **)` will be either `8` or `4` most likely.

Comment: The other possibility is that you have messed up malloc previous to this code through some error in code not shown here.

Answer (score 2):

As @TomKarzes pointed out,

> Both of your `sizeof` arguments are wrong. Think about what you're actually allocating. The first should be `sizeof(char *) * SIZE` and the second `sizeof(char) * SIZE`. Remember, the argument to `sizeof` in `malloc` should always have one less level of indirection than the resulting pointer type.

This is correct. It worked for me.

Comment: This is almost certainly not your real issue. Your code simply allocates too much memory in the loop, but otherwise is sound. Unless the first `malloc` fails of course. You should check that `malloc` doesn't return a null pointer.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde you're right. The `malloc` was only indirectly causing my program to segfault.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue here is not the incorrect `sizeof`, but more likely the call to the first `malloc` fails. I suspect the following change is the true fix to you problems.

```
char** arr = malloc(sizeof(char**)*(SIZE));
if (!arr) {
    // Handle the error
}
else {
    char** temp = arr;
    while(temp < arr + SIZE) {
        *temp = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(SIZE));
        temp++;
    }
}
```

I don't believe the incorrect `sizeof` calculation is really pertinent. Consider that (to my knowledge) `sizeof(char**) == sizeof(char*)`, so the first `malloc` actually allocates the correct amount of memory (supposing it actually succeeds). And the inner call to `malloc` shouldn't itself cause a segfault, but should just return a null pointer (unless you've really messed your memory up elsewhere in some unseen code). Rather, it's the indirection `*temp` that probably caused the segfault, and this would only happen if `temp` pointed past the end of the original allocation, which it won't (unless, again, the first `malloc` fails).